# Trying to find a video Card that is dual display that wil work on an older computer with ubuntu 14.04Lts

Tags: drivers, ati, software-installation, multiple-monitors

Hello everyone I was wondering if any one knows of any dual display graphics card that is PCI Express 16x that has easy to find/ easy to install(newbie) drivers that will work in Ubuntu 14.04LTS? The host has a 1.80GHz AMD Sempron 3200+ processor with an onboard ATI RADEON XPRESS 200 64 MB DDR 128 MB DDR, and 2.4GB of ram. It would be great if the card was cheap say less that $40. Will be used for some gaming but mostly web surfing/youtube/viemo watching.

Thanks for your time and input in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is easier than you think.  Although I've never actually done this myself, about a year ago I had an in-depth conversation with a mega-geek who swears that ANY graphics card with a single DVI port is in fact already capable of displaying two different images on two separate monitors, and that all you need is a DVI cable splitter, similar to this one priced under $10 at amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-DVISPL1DD-1-Feet-Digital-Splitter/dp/B00111EMMO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1418986339&sr=8-1&keywords=dvi+splitter&pebp=1418986343890](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00111EMMO)

Some still fancier graphics cards have two DVI ports, which my friend explains support up to four such displays, provided you purchase two splitters.

So it seems the only part of your question I have left to answer is which cards are easiest to support.  The best I can do is to list the last two marginally high end graphics cards I purchased which gave me no grief, and both were purchased from Amazon, but you don't have to use that source unless you want to.

The following card seemed an exceptional value and ranked fairly high in a list of benchmarks I found online.  It's very large fan is extremely quiet.

XFX AMD Radeon HD 7750 1GB GDDR5 DVI/HDMI/DisplayPort PCI-Express Video Card FX775AZNP4;FX-775A-ZNP4

I ordered another value priced display card which claims to depend entirely on ambient airflow to cool it.  The problem is that most computers don't permit airflow around their cards so it would have overheated in the case in which I used it had I not cut a large opening in the side of the case to let air in directly opposite this card.  The case I used was made of cardboard, so cutting the case was relatively easy.

Asus ATI Radeon HD6450 Silence 1 GB DDR3 VGA/DVI/HDMI Low Profile PCI-Express Video Card - EAH6450 SILENT/DI/1GD3(LP)

Both graphics cards automatically configured with Ubuntu 12.04 without the need for locating any sort of additional drivers.